# AutoMapper Exception: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, dto

I have an ASP.Net Core C# application & using `AutoMapper`

DTO

```
public class ApplicationUserDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string AdSoyad { get; set; }


        public string UserName { get; set; }


        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Pass { get; set; }

    }
```

Model

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            PassNotes = new Collection<PassNote>();
        }

        public string AdSoyad { get; set; }
        public string Adres { get; set; }
        public string Sehir { get; set; }
        public string PostaKodu { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PassNote> PassNotes { get; set; }
    }



public class PassNote
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }


        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

AutoMapper Configuration

```
public class MapProfile:Profile
    {
        public MapProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<PassNote, PassNoteDto>();
            CreateMap<PassNoteDto, PassNote>();
            CreateMap<ApplicationUser,ApplicationUserDto>();
            CreateMap<ApplicationUserDto, ApplicationUser>();
         
        }
    }
```

Signature

```
return await _appDbContext.ApplicationUser.Include(x => x.PassNotes).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> List(string id)
        {
            var applicationUser = await _applicationUserService.GetWithUserByIdAsync(id);
            return View(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDto>>(applicationUser));
        }
```

When the controller is return, it throws the below run time error.

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: Object -> IEnumerable`1 System.Object -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Recorder.Web.DTOs.ApplicationUserDto, Recorder.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

How to typecast/map this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would need to know the signature of `GetWithUserByIdAsync` but I'm going to assume that it returns a single user object. Automapper is just saying you can't map a single `ApplicationUser` to a collection of `ApplicationUserDto`. Try this instead:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string id)
{
    var applicationUser = await _applicationUserService.GetWithUserByIdAsync(id);
    return View(_mapper.Map<ApplicationUserDto>(applicationUser));
}
```

You also need to make sure that the view accepts the correct model type.

Comment: Thanks for support. My signature as shown below;

            return await _appDbContext.ApplicationUser.Include(x => x.PassNotes).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);

Comment: @Emin looks like a single object as suspected, did you try the solution?

Comment: I tried and getting ; 
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Recorder.Web.DTOs.ApplicationUserDto', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Recorder.Web.DTOs.ApplicationUserDto]'.

Comment: That's a different issue related to the structure of your view, either modify the view to accept a single `ApplicationUserDto` or if you really want a collection for some reason then pass the single user to the view in an array: `return View(new[] { _mapper.Map<ApplicationUserDto>(applicationUser) });`